# A problem of Limit

Tags: limits

please help with this problem of limits: $lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}{(\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}+3x)}$. WolframAlpha shows the answer is $-7/6$ but I don't understand why.

Comment: Surely you have not typed out the whole question.  It can't happen at all, what you have written. The limit as it stands is clearly infinity.

Comment: the limit is for minus infinity, that was my error. The complete expression that I put on WolframAlpha was: lim 7*x/(sqrt(9*x^2+7*x)-3*x) as x->-infinity, please check this and help me

Comment: Oh, so that is the problem! All good, I know the answer.

Comment: Can you tell me?.. please

Comment: I am in the process of answering your query. On posting, you shall be informed.

Comment: The other answer does justice.

Comment: Multiply an divide by something that cacels the root. Remember $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: I guess the simple multiply and divide is enough for this problem but with that way I get $\infty$. Using Binomial theorem, I'm not sure that the use is ok, works apparently but on the course of my sister did not learn about it

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative without the binomial theorem.

With $a=\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}$ and $b=3x$, you have $a+b$. Multiply with $\color{blue}{\tfrac{a-b}{a-b}}$ and then use $(a+b)\color{blue}{(a-b)}=a^2-b^2$ in the numerator and get the $9x^2$ out of the square root:

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}+3x & = \frac{\left(\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}+3x\right)\color{blue}{\left(\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}-3x\right)}}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}-3x}} \\
 & = \frac{7x}{|3x|\sqrt{1+\tfrac{7}{9x}}-3x}
\end{align}$$

Notice that $|3x|=-3x$ since $x<0$ and $\color{red}{\tfrac{7}{9x}}\to 0$; so:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}+3x\right) & = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{7x}{|3x|\sqrt{1+\color{red}{\tfrac{7}{9x}}}-3x} \\
& = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{7}{-3\sqrt{1+\color{red}{\tfrac{7}{9x}}}-3}\\
& =-\frac{7}{6}\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively (a bit less formal), complete the square:
$$9x^{2}+7x = \left(3x + \tfrac{7}{6} \right)^2 - \tfrac{49}{36}$$
and notice that for $x \to -\infty$:
$$\left(3x + \tfrac{7}{6} \right)^2 - \tfrac{49}{36} \approx \left(3x + \tfrac{7}{6} \right)^2$$
So:
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}+3x & = \sqrt{\left(3x + \tfrac{7}{6} \right)^2 - \tfrac{49}{36}}+3x \\
& \approx \sqrt{\left(3x + \tfrac{7}{6} \right)^2}+3x   && (x \to -\infty)\\
&= -\left(3x + \tfrac{7}{6} \right)+3x && (x < 0)\\
&= -\tfrac{7}{6}
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{9x^2+7x}+3x\right)
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\frac{7x}{\sqrt{9x^2+7x}-3x}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\frac{-7}{\sqrt{9\vphantom{^2}+7/x}+3}\right)\tag{2}\\
&=-\frac76\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{9x^2+7x}-3x$
$(2)$: divide numerator and denominator by $-x$ (which is positive)
$(3)$: take the limit

Answer (score 0):

Pull the $9x^2$ out of the square root and use the binomial theorem.

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{9x^{2}+7x}+3x\right) = \lim_{x\to-\infty}3x\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{9x}}\right)$$

(Recalling that since x is negative, 3x will be negative, and thus $\sqrt{9x^2} = -3x$.)

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}3x\left((1-1) - \frac{7}{18x} + \mathrm{O}(x^{-2})\right) = -\frac{7}{6}$$

It's quick-and-dirty, but does this shed a little light?

Comment: I feel confuse, whe you pulled $9x^{2}$ from where appeared the minus of the root?

Comment: In the fact that when dealing with negative numbers, $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$.